# Does a mobile phone with a locked SIM receive SMS?

Tags: security, mobile, sms

Imagine there is a mobile phone with phone number X. Someone has stolen it, but hasn't changed the SIM yet.

The owner contacts the operator, who locks that SIM.

If someone sends a SMS to that stolen phone with locked SIM, will the thief be able to read it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the features of phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but it may depend on the phone provider you are using. If this a real situation, it might worth a call.

I just googled it, most providers completely lock down the device so no features can be used (so no the thief would not be able to read your messages). You would need to call your service provider and prove your identity in order to have the phone unlocked and to be able to access your messages.

Comment: I need this information to make my mobile system (client on Android plus some server) stop working, when the SIM is locked. Therefore I thought of the following algorithm: When the mobile phone is stolen, she does 2 things: 1) Contacts the operator to lock the sim. 2) Requests a new confirmation code from my service. Upon step 2 my server sends SMS with a confirmation code to the owner and the mobile client asks for the code in order to continue working. The SMS is not delivered (because the SIM is locked) and the app stops working. What do you think of this approach?